# RuntimeError: Working outside of application context. , with context trying to add/fix

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am having issues where it is saying that the app is running outside of the application context , I have been trying to look at the flask forums to be able to see how to get the right formatting for this but im a little lost because ive tried quite a few things to fix it but I have not gotten it to work .

````
app.py(filename)
```
from email.policy import default
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import current_app
#from main2 import app
#from src.app import app
import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
       with app.app_context():
            current_app.name
            app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:''@localhost/flask'
            app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
            db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#db.create_all()
class Articles(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key= True)
    bottleName = db.Column(db.String(50))
    dateMeasured = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = datetime.datetime.now)
    replaceNowDistance = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key= True)
    distanceOff = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key= True)
    percentOff = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key= True)
    replacementDecision = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    def __init__(self, bottleName, replaceNowDistance):
        self.bottleName = bottleName
        self.replaceNowDistance = replaceNowDistance
     

@app.route('/get', methods = ['GET'])
def get_articles():
    return jsonify({"Hello": "World"})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

```
````

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74000056/13708022) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of your code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:''@localhost/flask'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
with app.app_context():
     db.create_all()
```

Of course you need to complete he configuration with SECRET_KEY ...